# Why HTML5 focus so much on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning HTML5. I see almost everything is linked to JS. Why is it so much JS focused than HTML/XHTML?

Comment: Do you have anything to prove your conclusion about HTML5 being JS oriented?

Comment: Geolocation API, Canvas, Web Storage, Web Workers etc.

Comment: My two cents: JavaScript is the only de facto language used in web browsers. (What other reason is needed? Also, the interfaces -- especially the DOM -- are defined "generically", but map well to ECMAScript concepts ;-)

Comment: (That aside, the interface designers also take effort to make it so. Consider that the DOM defines "className" for access to the "class" attribute as class is a reserved word in ECMAScript.)

Comment: @pst: `class` is used in many OO languages: '[This attribute has been renamed due to conflicts with the "class" keyword exposed by many languages.](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-58190037)'

Answer (score 1):

It's not per se.  Javascript is just a very common thing in quality UI's these days.  Designers and developers demand interaction on their interfaces that can in many cases only be accomplished via client-side interaction, which is what javascript gives you.  Because HTML 5 is cutting edge, it's logical that quality UI guys with expertise in javascript would be flexing their muscle.

HTML5 is responding to many things such as video and tweening that used to require plugins like Flash and Javascript to accomplish.  This will allow us to provide these "advanced" features more natively, improving usablity.  You'll already see this in examples like YouTube's html5 video delivery, which is compatible with mobile browsers that don't support Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quick short answer.

Javascript is handled client side and can enable asynchronous requests.  This makes pages much faster and allows for animations and content changes without reloads.

Comment: How does this make HTML5 different from HTML 4 and XHTML?

Comment: It doesn't.  It just explains why, when learning html5, a lot of what they are seeing is javascript.  html5 guides are newer and centered around web 2 standards which is why it seems like they incorporate more javascript than html4 and xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this: HTML5 will try to standardize the concept of Web applications. You can pretty much think of HTML5 as the mark-up that defines the user interface while Javascript is the language that allows you to do the application logic (ie. Ajax, User control callbacks).

If you've ever used the Android SDK, the iOS SDK, or Microsoft's WPF, you'll notice that the user interface is defined through XML constructs like input, buttons, etc. While you used, Java, Objective C, or C# to do all the programming logic. Now, HTML 5 and Javascript are being advanced towards the same paradigm.